# SharePoint 2013 calculated column -compare dates

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I thought this is easy but somehow I didn't get this right.

I entered the following formula in the calculated column but the outcome is incorrect.

For example, when `[Target_Finish]=10/10/2019`, the column should return "FY20", but it returns "FY19".

```
=if([Target_Finish]="","",if([Target_Finish]<"9/30/2019","FY19",if(and([Target_Finish]>"9/30/2019",[Target_Finish]<"9/30/2020"),"FY20","FY21")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date string you are using in comparison to Date object for correct comparison.

For that you need to use `DATE` function.

> **Syntax:**
>   DATE(year,month,day)

Try using below formula:

```
=IF([Target_Finish]="","",IF([Target_Finish]<DATE(2019,9,30),"FY19",IF(AND([Target_Finish]>DATE(2019,9,30),[Target_Finish]<DATE(2020,9,30)),"FY20","FY21")))
```

**Reference**:

[DATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/date-function-b91bef00-4b5b-4ee0-b80e-06e68b1dff29).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote(^) and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

While comparing, you have compared a Date column with a string "9/30/2019". To convert it into date value, you should use DATEVALUE() function inside the formula. Use this formula below.

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Target_Finish]),"",IF([Target_Finish]<DATEVALUE("9/30/2019"),"FY19",IF(AND([Target_Finish]>DATEVALUE("9/30/2019"),[Target_Finish]<DATEVALUE("9/30/2020")),"FY20","FY21")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have entered date in a wrong format I think, Please try to compare date in following format.

```
=IF([Target_Finish]="","",IF([Target_Finish]<DATE(2019,9,30),"FY19",IF(AND([Target_Finish]>DATE(2019,9,30),[Target_Finish]<DATE(2020,9,30)),"FY20","FY21")))
```